# Refresh Windows form while it calls a function of different class

Tags: c++, winforms, timer

My windows form application calls a function from a different class. This functions takes about 20 minutes to run.. I want to update my windows form every 5 sec.. (Not call the function again... but refresh the windows form). I know i have to use timer functions .. 
Can anyone help me this? I m able to call functions again after timer is elapsed.. but i just want to refresh the form..

thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to use a separate thread, and have the form poll to see if it has finished.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1245551/763026

Answer (score 0):

Have a  look at the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) component. This event-based object will run your function off the UI thread ([DoWork](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.dowork)) and can report progress back to the UI ([ProgressChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx)) as well as notify the UI when the function is complete ([RunWorkerCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted.aspx)).