# Run a backgroundworker process every '5' minutes in Winforms

Tags: winforms, backgroundworker

I have a Winforms app in which I want to run a background worker process every 5 minutes. I am using .Net 4.0.

Would this be possible with 'BackgoundWorker' component?

Comment: Can you check this ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241618/backgroundworker-thread-and-timer-logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

u can use C# Timer--->

```
DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
TimeSpan interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
dispatcherTimer.Interval = interval;
dispatcherTimer.Start();
```

Comment: Use the WinForms timer object vs. DispatcherTimer might be preferable so he's not pulling in WPF if he's not otherwise using it.